# unzip command in Linux fails to decompress Unicode files from archive

Tags: bash, unicode, utf-8, scripting, unzip

Under Linux, I am trying to unzip a zip file which contains files with filenames using foreign characters.

When unzip tries to decompress the file it escapes the file name as ''#Uxxxx'' and then fails with mismatching "local" filename.

I am using ubuntu, unzip 6.00 and running it from the command line (I need it to be run from a script).

Any help, ideas, greatly appreciated.

Comment: I see that this has been labeled "off-topic", which is really a bummer, since I'm seeing exactly the same error (except with filenames that contain Arabic characters).   Stackoverflow is getting less and less useful because of responses like this.  Would somebody at least have the decency to say why it's off-topic, or where in stackoverflow such a question would be on-topic?  (BTW, the answer of using -O cp396 did not work in my case.)

Comment: @MikeMaxwell I know in the past usually when some question is off-topic and looks useful on another Stack Exchange site, it will move there. I believe that this question should be on unix.stackexchange.com. I hope someone from Stack Exchange staff notice it and move there, because even I find this question from my Google Search search.

Comment: Thanks, @bayuah.  Makes sense.  I'll just add that it would be helpful in such a case to have a pointer to where the question has been moved.  Otherwise a simple "closed, off topic" label just sounds snotty.  (That's not a comment on you, because your answer is helpful; it's a comment on stackoverflow and its moderators.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code:

```
unzip -O cp936 (filename)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works for me - but with `cp1250` and `utf8` for cyrillic symbols

Comment: Sometimes you don't have the `-O utf8` option in you version of unzip (for ex. when running unzip 6.00 on a Debian 11 Bullseye) => in such case, use option `-UU` instead.